# How can I load core dumps of intel processes running under rosetta2 in apple silicon?

Tags: macos, command-line, xcode, apple-silicon, open-source

Using `lldb` on a M1 Mac, I can successfully run and attach to a x64 process and have commands like `bt` showing useful information.

However if I save a memory dump and try to load it in a different debug session, no debug symbols are loaded, and all I get are hex memory addresses.

So far what I observe is:

- intel process on intel: live debug works, dump debug works
- arm process on arm: live debug works, dump debug works
- intel process on arm: live debug works, dump debug *can't load symbols*

This was tested with `lldb` running both natively (arm) and in emulated x64 (by running with `/usr/bin/arch -x86_64 lldb`). I also tried loading the "intel-on-arm" process in an lldb running on an intel mac and had the same result.

Is there any way to get symbols working for "intel-on-arm" post-mortem debugging?

Comment: This capability would be amazing. I wonder if you need to save / not strip symbols and debugging information at compile time for this to work. Plus, Rosetta involvement of recompiled code makes this amazingly complex to my eye…